# AWS EC2 describe images on creation date more than 7 days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Fetching the AMI's Id's on creation date greater than 7 days. Tried giving the query as below.

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=name,Values=Jenkins_*" --region us-east-1 --query 'sort_by(Images, &CreationDate)[].Name'.
```

This command is giving me list of AMI's. Is there any way to fetch the AMI's whose creation date is more than 7 days?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To query Jenkins images older than 7 days:

```
aws ec2 describe-images \
    --filters "Name=name,Values=Jenkins_*" \
    --query 'Images[?CreationDate<`2019-06-18`]'
```

To sort that list and retrieve just the image names:

```
aws ec2 describe-images \
    --filters "Name=name,Values=Jenkins_*" \
    --query 'Images[?CreationDate<`2019-06-18`] | sort_by(@, &CreationDate)[].Name'
```

That results in a list, such as:

```
[
    "Jenkins_Spot_Slave",
    "Jenkins_Persistant_RPM_AMI",
    "Jenkins_slave",
    "Jenkins_Image",
    "Jenkins_2.173-f42de1ed-a17a-4d6f-ab78-60f840d38dbb-ami-0f4ed2a00254db81a.4"
]
```