# Deleting AWS AMIs older than a certain date

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli

I'm running a backup strategy which consists of creating new AWS machine AMIs nightly.  Until recently, this was combined with deletion of the previous night's backup, but now we're keeping them for 30 days.

The script line I have in place is as follows:

OLD_AMI_IDs=`/usr/bin/aws ec2 describe-images --owners ########## \ --filters "Name=tag:Backup,Values=TRUE" "Name=tag:InstanceID,Values=$I_ID" \ --query="Images[*][ImageId][*]" --output text`

The $I_ID value is passed to the script from an external process.  But now, I'm unable to switch from simply deleting the existing AMI to replace it with a new one, to deleting AMIs older than 30 days.  This requires the use of an extended query string, I suspect - but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Any help appreciated.

Alan

I've tried substituting --query="Images[*].{date:CreationDate}" for my query string just to return the creation date, but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56754415/aws-ec2-describe-images-on-creation-date-more-than-7-days

Comment: Also, note that the Amazon Data Livecycle Manager is a managed service that can do exactly what you describe. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the list of AMIs that are eligible for deletion. Modify the command below with your specific values:

```
OLD_AMI_IDS=$(aws ec2 describe-images --owners YOUR_OWNER_ID --filters "Name=tag:Backup,Values=TRUE" "Name=tag:InstanceID,Values=$I_ID" --query "Images[?CreationDate<='$(date --date='30 days ago' +%Y-%m-%d)' && State!='available'].ImageId" --output text)
```

Replace YOUR_OWNER_ID with the appropriate owner ID of the AMIs you want to delete. Additionally, ensure that you have set the I_ID variable to the instance ID.